# Pushing dist subtree to GH-Pages

Tags: git, maven, github

I'm trying to automate my build chain to push my generated doc to github gh-pages.
Here's the workflow:
Jenkins checkout the remote sources to a local master branch.
It builds the project locally (generates binary to target/staging, e.g. mvn site site:staging).

Then I've a shell post step:

```
git push origin --delete gh-pages #removes the existing remote gh-pages branch
git checkout -b gh-pages # creates a local gh-page branch
git rm -rf . #untrack everything
git add target/staging #adds the generated doc to tracking
git commit -am "Added staging" commit changes
git subtree split --prefix target/staging -b gh-pages #subtree branch to gh-pages branch
```

So, I thought it was something like this, but a weird 'Branch 'gh-pages' is not an ancestor of commit ...' Hits me in the face...

Has anyone got the solution to be able to push this subtree in the remote github banch?

Thank you in advance

Disclaimer's, I tested github-site-plugin and scm-publisher but I've too many files in my site for these plugins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to delete the local `gh-pages` branch:

```
$ git branch -D gh-pages
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice shell on github that does this: https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy

However, I'm always open for an inline answer :)